# What does M1 mean in a maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, versioning, maven

I've been using maven for a while, and I often review repositories before selected what version I want to use.  I don't entirely understand what the extensions mean.

I know that when I see extensions like -RC1 and -RC2 that means release candidates.   When I see a version without an extension, I assume that means a released version.  But what does an extension of -M1 or -M2 mean?

Example:

2.8-RC1

2.8

2.8-M1  ??

Comment: Apache Tomcat Version 9.0.0.M1 is another example that uses M1 (for those who search for this).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

M1 means Milestone 1, it's a release name, like beta or alpha.
RC means Release Candidate.

A milestone means that the application got a huge improvement from the todo list.
A release candidate is a release that can be the final release unless some major bugs are found.

To quote the ASF:

> Releases that only represent a project milestone and are intended only
> for bleeding-edge developers working outside the project are called
> "alpha".

---

**Resources :**

- [Wikipedia - Software release life cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)
- [ASF release types](https://www.apache.org/legal/release-policy.html#release-types)

Comment: thanks, so when looking for a finished product, RC is better than M.

Comment: In Wikipedia the milestone version is mentioned in the pre-alpha stage.

Comment: Pretty confusing, when the ASF in the same paragraph of their release policy declare that _releases are packages that have been approved for general public release_, and at the same time state that milestone release _are intended only for bleeding-edge developers_ ... Does the general public consist only of bleeding-edge developers?
To disorient a bit more, we find quotes like _**Apache Maven Surefire 3.0.0-M6** This is the current stable version of Apache Maven Surefire._ (from https://maven.apache.org/surefire/download.cgi, as seen on the 2022-04-19)