# Maven upload 64MB jar does not finish

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, artifactory

I have a multi-module SpringBoot application that I deploy to artifactory. Unfortunately the upload to artifactory fails because the Jenkins build checks if the file exists and it doesn't because the file does not get uploaded.

Sub-module gets uploaded successfully:

```
[INFO] Uploading to snapshots: <jar path>
[INFO] Uploaded to snapshots: <jar path>  (241 kB at 759 kB/s)
```

Main app module logs :

```
 Uploading to snapshots: <jar>
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project <project>: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact <application module jar> in snapshots (<artifactory path>) -> [Help 1]
```

As you can see above, for sub-modules I get also "Uploaded" message. For the main app module i get only "uploading", not "uploaded". Main difference that I can see is the size. SpringBoot app jar is 60MB and the sub-modules are KB. I think the build triggers the upload but then directly checks if it was uploaded but maybe the upload did not finish...
What can I do to fix this and get a successfull build?

Comment: [How do I deploy large files to Artifactory?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-deploy-large-files-to-artifactory/). [When Using Artifactory’s REST API, Is There a Size Limit on File Uploads?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/when-using-artifactorys-rest-api-is-there-a-size-limit-on-file-uploads/)

Comment: It would be helpfull to see the full logging output as well as the full pom file which is used and how you are calling Maven ...without that it's imposibble to say samething about the reasons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had double  that defined the repositories, both in parent pom and in the application module pom.
I don't know exactly why this caused Maven to block the upload of the jar to Artifactory but I am certain that this was the problem.

From my point of view, 2.8.2 is ok being the latest full release and there can be business reasons why we want to upload to Artifactory also SNAPSHOT versions.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. version `2.8.2` of `maven-deploy-plugin` was released in 2014 - 8 years ago, it is definitely worth to try update it (and `maven` as well)
2. deploying `SNAPSHOT` versions does not make sense: there is no reliable way to work with `SNAPSHOT` dependencies, it is like playing improved russian roulette with five rounds in a revolver - there are only two states of such artifact cached locally: it either stale or you have no idea what has been changed.

---

Special note for guys who like to flirt with snapshot versions.

Snapshot concept have nothing in common with SDLC, that is just a poor attempt to place something unusable into another [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitive_Media_Library) or partition.

If your need to build some kind of feature-preview/nightly releases maven does allow to do that without affecting entire SDLC:

```bash
mvn -e --batch-mode -Prelease release:clean release:prepare \
 -Darguments='-DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository=... -DaltSnapshotDeploymentRepository=...' \
# version convention for fp release
 -DreleaseVersion=1.0.0-${sha} \
# continue staying on snapshot version
 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
 -DpushChanges=false \
 -DpreparationGoals="clean deploy"
```

People who run `mvn deploy` against `SNAPSHOT` version just do not understand what they are really doing and what are the consequences. That should be at least `mvn deploy -Dmaven.install.skip=true`

Comment: @andrey-b-panfilov, Your post does not actually answer the OP's question. `maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2` may be 8 years old, but it is the prior release version to current, so not really "obsolete". Also, version "-Mx" indicates it's a "[milestone release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3687216/598141)", so not final (ie: a alpha/beta release), so may not be suitable for all, making `2.8.2` the latest full release. OP does not indicate maven version in use either.

Comment: And I can't believe I'd be defending the use of SNAPSHOTs, but there are very legitimate SDLC reasons to deploy SNAPSHOTS, at least it to internal remote repositories, as valid as releasing an alpha/beta/milestone release.

Comment: @IanW, the question was: "What can I do to fix this and get a successfull build?", the answer "Try to update or disable" - I do see some logic there, moreover some maven versions do have issues with deployment, for example: [WAGON-568](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-568).

Comment: @IanW https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ (please check that for latest releases of maven-deploy-plugin as well as maven-install-plugin)...

Comment: The answer related to SNAPSHOT makes no sense because it is useful to use SNAPSHOT versions.

Comment: @khumarbase, something odd. No [release](https://github.com/apache/maven-deploy-plugin/releases), no [announcement](https://blogs.apache.org/maven/category/Plugin+Release) and my knowledge is 3 weeks out of date. Oh well. 2.8.2 is still the "prior version", so not that out of date.

Comment: First releases are not announced on GitHub.. please check the referenced page (https://maven.apache.org/plugins) second announcements are made on https://lists.apache.org/list.html?announce@maven.apache.org The blog has not been updated correct... I recommend to upgrade yes but it is not the cause of the problem...

Comment: At least  we agree SNAPSHOTs have value and updating not likely to resolve the issue. Suggest OP try `mvn -X` for more info and check artifactory and other settings per my comment refs.